# (D)SFML update position of shape automatically

Tags: graphics, sfml, d, transformable

I created a simple little programm in D with the D-bindings to SFML. And I'm currently reading about the custom transformations and custom shapes.

Now I created a class

```d
class Animal : Drawable, Transformable
{
    mixin NormalTransformable;

    Shape body;
    string name;

    this(Shape sh, string name) {
        this.body = sh;
        this.name = name;
    }

    override void draw(RenderTarget target, RenderStates state = RenderStates.Default) {
        body.position = this.position;
        target.draw(body);
    }
}
```

This is D code, but I think most of the stuff except the `mixin` should be quite the same in C++.

Now my question is mainly about this line `body.position = this.position;` in the `draw` method.

Is it necessary to update the position of the shape manually? This seems a bit wrong but I do not find any ressource that shows me how to automate this process. Also doing this in `draw` feels a bit like a deadly sin to me.

So basically my question is:

How do I draw my own drawables according to the stuff that happens to it by the methods from the transformable interface.

Or even simpler:

How do I synchronize the position, scale, rotation, ... from the object and the shape automatically?